# Zoomable sunburst chart in percentages

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to D3 and I hope you can help out. I'm working on a sunburst chart divided into inner and outer layers, where inner layer represents a group and outer layers represent subgroups. Here's a working example for reference: jsfiddle.net/9gpL308y/1/ (and here's the original fiddle I used as a starting point: jsfiddle.net/j9WnB/64/)

Currently, each inner layer adds up to a number based on its categories' values in the outer layer and categories behave the same with their subcategories. What I need is for each layer to display as percentage (out of 100 that all groups on the same layer should add up to) and scale to appropriate size. Take this image for example:

[image of the wanted chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4geEL.jpg)

Working example would be extremely helpful. I found some topics on this problem but I couldn't get it to work with provided advice. To be honest I still don't understand fully what's going on in here (I was never good at geometry).

tl;dr: How to make sunburst chart from the fiddle above display data as percentage and have arcs scale appropriately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little to do with geometry in this case (except positioning your label, but this is what `arc.centroid` provides). To get your percentages you just need to divide an extent of the child node by the extent of its parent.

```
                var center = arc.centroid(d);
                g.append("text")
                 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + center + ")")
                 .text(function(_) {
                    if (d.parent == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    var percentage = 100 * d.dx / d.parent.dx; // that's it!
                    return d3.format(",.2f")(percentage) + "%";
                 })
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gpL308y/2/

For educational purposes you can dump all the nodes of the partition layout and then find how do they match visual picture. You can also read about those `parent`, `dx`, etc. at the documentation on partition layout: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Partition-Layout.md

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your example gives each group of the inner circle a percentage that together add up to 100 but the distribution is not correct or at least not what I'm aiming for. They're evenly spaced, but shouldn't be. I added more data to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/zyrypoL7/

From the data I'm working with, Group 8 (for example) should add up to 20.92% but here it's 7.54%, as most other groups are. Group 24 should add up to 5.31% instead of 8%. Please check the image above for reference or warn me if I'm missing something or asking for something weird. :)

Comment: Recently I returned to this and figured out your example was right from the start. I was just working with what I thought was correct data so things didn't add up as original calculations suggested. Now that data is fixed, it works. Thanks again. :)